# How is this Schottky diode helping discharge the filter capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, schottky

I'm trying to filter the possible bounce of the mechanical switch S1. For a simulation of a sequence of pulses the voltage on C1 keeps adding, it discharges very slow, so after some 10 ms bounces the output signal is activated:

[image]

If I place the Schottky diode D1 then it works much better (saw this in some book) but I don't understand why. This is the result:

[image]

But anyway the voltage in InputBySW is still increasing, is there a way to improve this?

EDIT:

I guess the effect of the diode is just its leakage current helping discharge the capacitor:

[image]

So my question remains, how to decrease the discharge time of the capacitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept the zener on the circuit in order to use this leak current to help discharge the capacitor. I ended up using a different circuit because I needed a pulse on the output even if the switch is kept active.

Answer (score 1):

It discharges very slowly because of the 20K resistor between it and the ground.
What you need is a ON/ON switch which connects either to V+ or to GND. When it connects to GND, the capacitor discharges faster, whereas when connected to V+ it charges gradually thanks to R1.
To discharge C1 immediately, you can add a schottky diode from from C1 to SW1 bypassing R1 (not visible on the schematic).
R2 prevents bounces and spikes to hit the input before being swallowed by the capacitor.

Values of R1, R2 and C1 are aproximative and up to your discretion.

The Zener diode D1 is better than a voltage divider with two resistors because bounce spikes can be much higher than the supplied voltage. The zenner will always give a predictable voltage while a voltage divider will only divide the voltage it's given and may be higher than expected.
Of course you can replace the zenner diode with a resistor if you want or doubling the zenner diode with a resistor in case the switch would be floating or if you can't put a ON/ON switch.
If you can't use such a switch, then we must think about reducing the impedance of the resistor to ground. Or something else. But then, it will consume a little bit more power because the supply is 24V.

The schotky diode D2 prevents reverse current which happens inevitably with switch bounces.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frJeMR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbwASs.png)</sup>

The second schematic shows a solution where ON/ON switch is not an option because we want to use a momentary switch. The idea is to fill C1 with already divided voltage. The zenner limits the voltage to the base voltage. C1 is only 1uF and R2 10K. Discharge time should 40x shorter than with 20uF + 20K.

Comment: If you zoom the images you can see its a 10uF capacitor.

Comment: Connecting the diode between ground and SW doesn't make sense, it will not help discharging the capacitor. What I want is a faster capacitor discharge, I'm happy with charge time. The long charge time already filters small spikes but continuous spikes can be a trouble if the capacitor doesn't discharge fast enough.

Comment: The choice of a voltage divider or a resistor zener combination is just a matter of choice and the result is the same.

Comment: @PedroNF See my edited answer.

Comment: This is a nice solution but in my case I need to debounce the switch that is connected to 24V, so the switch will be bouncing on/off for a short period. So a two way switch is not applicable here.

Comment: Voltage divider R4/R5 is calculated to polarize the transistor so if I lower R5 I'll have faster discharge but then I have to lower R4 which makes a faster charge so less filtering. I was looking for a solution that could "magically" kind of short circuit the capacitor when there is no 24V coming from the switch.

Comment: @PedroNF You mean the switch is a tact switch? Else what prevent you to put a two-way switch. I don;t understand.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you can't modelize, or simulate switch bouncing. It's too random and unpredictable. You have to observe directly what happens with an oscilloscope and then apply a strategy. Why do you think you need 20uF? IMO 1uF should be enough and you divide the discharge time by 20 already. You can reduce R4 and R5 for the same purpose. As long as R4+R5 >= 10K ohm it should be ok.

Comment: Yes I wanted too much filtering I guess. I've added a diode in series with R6 so that the transistor switches on later (InputBySW voltage needs to raise more) and this allowed to use a 10uF capacitor. I have a delay of 46 ms from the switch on to the output toogle.

Comment: Why a diode ins erie with R6? In which direction? What for?

Comment: Anyway, the very best solution is to try to find a way to use a two way switch with GND. I think there are temporary switches built that way. If that's what you need. This will be your "magic solution".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109130/discussion-between-pedro-nf-and-fredled).